# how to update a db value

Tags: java, mysql

I have a mysql database here I have columns for oldNominalValue and newNominalValue. I have 12 rounds in which at the each end of the round I update my new and nominal values. At the end of each round I need to set my newnominalvalue to oldnominalvalue how can I do this. Can anyone please tell me how to do this. Thanks for your time.

```
 String CMF= rs.getString("comapanyName");
                        String ONV = rs.getString("oldNominalValue");
                        String NNV = rs.getString("newNominalValue");
                        // String NS = rs.getString("numberOfShares");
                        // System.out.print(CMF);
                        nominalvalue = Integer.parseInt(ONV);
                        //int nv = 1;
                        T =  randNum / 100;
                        RT = T * nominalvalue;
                        newnominalvalue = nominalvalue - RT;

                        st = con.createStatement();
                        String query08= "update where " + FS + " (comapanyName,newnominalValue,oldNominalValue,PLock) VALUE ('" + gameName + "','Financial','" + CMF + "',', " + newnominalvalue + "," + nominalvalue + "', 0 )";
                        st.executeUpdate(query08);
```

Comment: what have you actually tried? I assume you are familiar with sql and persistence libraries?

Comment: You are mixing update and insert syntax, which makes no sense.  Please add sample input and output data which explains what you are trying to do here.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen yes I've messed up with the insert syntax can you give me the update syntax if possible since I am new to mysql. Thanks for your valuable time.

Answer (score 0):

Are you familiar with SQL syntax? There are some issues with your update query. Also, try using a prepared statement instead of a regular statement when using parameters and use proper resource management (ensure the statement gets closed again). See the sample below:

```
String statement = "UPDATE <your-table> SET newnominalValue = ?, oldNominalValue = ? WHERE <your-id-column> = ?";
try(PreparedStatement updateStmt = con.prepareStatement(statement)) {
  updateStmt.setString(1, NNV);
  updateStmt.setString(2, ONV);
  updateStmt.setString(3, FS); // not sure what FS is in your code, or what type it is

  updateStmt.executeUpdate();
}
```

Also, please use sensible and camelCased names in Java, it will help you and others in the long run to maintain the code. Variable names like 'T', 'RT' and 'FS' are most likely to confuse people and makes things a lot harder.